# Terminator does not add to dock icon when opened via Ctrl+Alt+T

Tags: 18.04, gnome-terminal, dock, terminator

**UBUNTU 18.04** and **Gnome3** desktop.

I have installed `Terminator` and set it to be default terminal application. So, when I press `Ctrl+Alt+T` it pops up instead of default terminal application. I also added it to the favorites, as you see,

[image]

If there is not any open `Terminator` windows currently, and I run it by typing `Terminator` and clicking it from Dash or just clicking to the dock icon, it opens and one window open identifier(that little orange ball) goes to the dock icon.

[image]

After that, if I run it via typing `Terminator` and clicking it or via `Ctrl+Alt+T`, the additional windows add up.

[image]

HOWEVER, If I do the **first** launch via `Ctrl+Alt+T`, then it opens it and displays(on dock) as a seperate icon,

[image]

Please focus on the two `Terminator` symbols on the dock.

SO, why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it seems to be a bug in Terminator. You can try to fix it by modifying `/usr/bin/terminator` so that it sets the program name correctly.

Change line 36 from

`from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk`

to

`from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib`

and write

`GLib.set_prgname(APP_NAME)`

after

`dbg ("%s starting up, version %s" % (APP_NAME, APP_VERSION))`

The changes might be lost if the application updates, but hopefully it will also get fixed by the developers. See this [pull request](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/pull/628).

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the file: `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`
2. Modify the "NoDisplay=false" in file: `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop`